# Why are certain CSS properties not applied to a:visited?

Tags: css

I have some link styles for our website and the CSS is as follows:

```css
a:link {
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0676b3;
}

a:visited {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #A5C2DB;
    border-radius: .1875em;
    padding: 0 .1875em;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danferth/xmewM/) to show how they are **supposed** to look in their different states:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
/*  these styles are for presentation of the link states they are NOT the styles in my stylesheet*/

a.link {
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: .875em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0676b3;
}
a.visited {
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a.hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #A5C2DB;
  border-radius: 0.1875em;
  padding: 0 0.1875em;
}
```

```html
<a class="link">Regular Link</a>
<br />
<a class="visited">Visited Link</a>
<br />
<a class="hover">Hovered Link</a>
```

:link = blue text no decoration

:visited = grey text underlined

:hover = white text with light blue background

The `:link` and `:hover` work fine but for some reason the `:visited` state refuses to show the underline. in Chrome and Firefox using firebug or the inspector I can see the `:visited` style in action and the text is grey in color, only it refuses the `underline` state.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: its working perfect for me. at least the supposed to look like states.

Comment: Your fiddle only shows what the styles are supposed to look like, but we need to see your actual code.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn the actual css is in the question above, the fiddle was only to show the state desired.  As far as the HTML it is just the link tags nothing there that would affect it so did not include.

Comment: I added some dummy links to his fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/xmewM/9/). By adding and removing the `decoration:none;` property, I was able to prove that the `a:link` declaration is indeed overriding the `a:visited` underline property, even though Chrome inspector says otherwise...

Comment: @gmeben that question is about `:visited` links but mine is about a problem with the css not the application of the `:visited` selector.

Comment: @NathanArthur awesome I guess, so I'm not crazy in seeing it is being overridden.  Any ideas on a fix.  I never until now used `:visited` so this is quite frustrating.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong - it just doesn't work that way (anymore). Styling of :visited  was used as a security hole, so browser manufacturers basically eliminated alternate styling for :visited except for a handful of properties (e.g. 'color', 'background-color')

See: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/