# A workaround for background-position on a:visited links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I've read here that background-position is no longer allowed to be modified for a:visited links in CSS due to a security vulnerability. ([MSDN info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)) I've seen a few items that suggest there is a workaround with jQuery or javascript, but I'm not fluent in these languages. Can someone walk through a workaround for a Wordpress setup?

Currently, I have this CSS with the goal to move a sprite image indicating that an article has been read (link has been visited):

```
.widget-area .widget_recent_entries a {
height: 19px;
width: 90%;
padding-left: 19px;
background: transparent url("images/link-check.png") no-repeat;
}

.widget-area .widget_recent_entries a:hover {
background-position: 0 -19px !important;
}

background-position: 0 -19px !important;
}
```

I'm not sure if its possible to do the what I'm looking for but if it is, I'm sure a step-by-step would help a lot of people with the same issue and limited experience with jQuery or javascript. For instance, if there is a little code, where in the theme do I put it (header/footer) ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `I've seen a few items that suggest there is a workaround with jQuery or javascript` Any links??? I'd be suprised it exists any workaround for that

Comment: The only way I can think of is if you manually save where the user had visited (localStorage for example) and use JS to render the links differently. Not the best way to go.

Comment: @A.Wolff a couple entries I saw on the subject: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357588/styling-avisited-links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357588/styling-avisited-links) and [http://jsfiddle.net/prJUt/](http://jsfiddle.net/prJUt/)

Comment: This is outdated answer now. Actually i don't know any workaround for your use case. Like suggested zbove, you could use any persistent data client side as cookie/localstorage but this wouldnt be équivalent to :visited pseudo class