# Download link not changing color after being visited

Tags: html, css

I have a link in html that downloads a file.

```
<a href=".../file.html">A3. Professionalism and Public Relations</a>
```

In my css file I have this specified:

```
a:hover, a:visited{
    color: orange;
}
```

When I hover, the link becomes orange but when I click on it, it keeps its default color. I know my css works for non-download links. What should I do for download links?

Comment: Can someone find a dupe for this?

Comment: Similar issue can be found here. Apparently not supported in some browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320351/problems-with-avisited

Comment: See this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector).

Comment: And see the first answer in the dupe. Thanks @AlexJohnson.

Comment: @PraveenKumar just to clarify from what I read, `color` is still supported for `a:visited` because it works for other links. The OP in the linked question had problems with `underline` and not `color`

Comment: @ybce True. It should work. But not for downloaded files. They don't even open (or leave a trace in the history), FYI.

Comment: @PraveenKumar  Makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: I think it's improperly marked as a duplicate. The real issue is with the hyperlink that references file rather than webpage and the answer could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656411/using-css-visited-property-for-href-to-a-file