# CSS button image :hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!doctype html>

<title>Site Maintenance</title>
<style>
body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; background: #666a73; }
body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666a73; }
article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; }
#button1 {
height: 50px;
width: 250px;
}
#button1:hover {
width: 300px;
height: 74px;
}
#button1:visited {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
}

</style>
<body>
<article>
<div>
<a href="test"><input type="image" id="button1"          
style="height:50px;width:250px;" src="button.png" /></a>
</div> 
</article>
</body>
```

Does anyone have an Idea why the on hover event doesn't work? Im not sure why its not srinking the button to size 0,0 or why it doesnt on hover enlarge it.

Comment: rly? <a><input></a>?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Agreed, there is ZERO reason to wrap the input in a link...especially one that doesn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove your inline style from input element:

```
<input type="image" id="button1" src="button.png" />
```

Inline styles have priority over declared styles, including your `:hover` style.

```css
body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; background: #666a73; }
body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666a73; }
article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; }
#button1 {
height: 50px;
width: 250px;
}
#button1:hover {
width: 300px;
height: 74px;
}
#button1:visited {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<title>Site Maintenance</title>
<body>
<article>
<div>
<a href="test"><input type="image" id="button1" src="button.png" /></a>
</div> 
</article>
</body>
```

Comment: This works dandy but the :visited doesn't work it the image still remains. And ideas?

Comment: @Gmanc2 I've been trying to solve that problem, and discovered it's a feature of newest browsers versions, according to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320351/problems-with-avisited). I changed the style to get `:visited` of your anchor like that `a:visited #button1 {
        width: 0 !important;
        height: 0 !important;
    }`

It will not change the attributes of width and height, how the new security says at this [link](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add !important after your css style changes to overwrite inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

Seems don't work because the type='image'   don't change  try using a type='button' like in the sample below

```
<!doctype html>

  <title>Site Maintenance</title>
  <style>
  body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; background: #666a73; }
  body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666a73; }
  article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; }
  #button1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  }
  #button1:hover { 
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 74px;
  }
  #button1:visited {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  }

  #button2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  }
  #button2:hover { 
  background-color : yellow;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 74px;
  }
  #button2:visited {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  }


  </style>
  <body>
    <article>
      <div>
        <a href="test">
          <input type="image" id="button1"             style="height:50px; width:250px;" src="button.png" />
        </a>
      </div> 
       <div>
      <a href="test">
          <input type="button" id="button2"    value='TEST'         style="height:50px; width:250px;" src="button.png" />
        </a>
      </div>    
    </article>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

### try this

https://jsfiddle.net/fnkq0b7r/2/

```
<!doctype html>

<title>Site Maintenance</title>
<style>
body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; background: #666a73; }
body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666a73; }
article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; }

#button1 img{
height: 50px;
width: 250px;
}
#button1:hover img{
width: 300px;
 height: 74px;
 }
 </style>
 <body>

<div>
<a href="test"  id="button1">
 <img     src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
 </a>
 </div> 

</body>
```