# Why doesn't my <a> tag's :visited css rule add a border?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a small vertical line next to a link when it's been visited.

```css
.navigation a:visited {
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="w">W</div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">hello</a></li>
      <li><a href="one.html">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="two.html">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="three.html">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the life of me, I can't get the border to change on visited. It works on `:hover`. I've tried `!important`, I've tried defining the `a` default to have a `border: 0px solid black` that is then, in my mind, 'modified' to be `3px`. None of it is working. Is this just not a possible thing to do?

To clarify, other things, such as `color`, are applying on `:hover`. So the purple bit works.

Comment: For security reasons, modern browsers limit the styles that can be applied to `:visited` elements. Border is not one that is allowed. You aren't crazy, it just isn't possible (with CSS alone, anyway).

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10320351/2930477

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MDN (about the `:visited` pseudo-class):

> Note: For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit the styles you can apply using an element selected by this pseudo-class: only color, background-color, border-color, border-bottom-color, border-left-color, border-right-color, border-top-color, outline-color, column-rule-color, fill and stroke. Note also that the alpha component will be ignored: the alpha component of the not-visited rule is used instead (except when the opacity is 0, in that case the whole color is ignored, and the one of the not-visited rule is used).
>
> Though the color can be changed, the method getComputedStyle will lie and always give back the value of the non-visited color.
>
> For more information on the limitations and the motivation for them, see Privacy and the :visited selector.

[(source)](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

However, you can set the color. So you can try to create a workaround like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/1mbv2peg/1/

It doesn't seem to work if your set the 'transparent' color first (because the alpha component is ignored):
https://jsfiddle.net/1mbv2peg/

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp

> Browsers limits the styles that can be set for a:visited links, due to
>   security issues.
>
> Allowed styles are:
>
> - color
> - background-color
> - border-color (and border-color for separate sides)
> - outline color
> - column-rule-color
> - the color parts of fill and stroke

Answer (score -2):

Maybe use jquery to add a new class?

```
$("a:visited").addClass("is_visited");
```

maybe wrap it in a document.ready call.

Comment: If this would be possible, this would be a big leak in browsers... Imagine how it would be possible to scan a users browsing history.
Please read: https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/